# Android:How to set option menus dynamically with OnClickListener in CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-cursoradapter

I have set a `ListView` with a custom CursorAdapter in MainActivity, and when "EDIT" menu is clicked, the CursorAdapter changes its View to set visibility of `CheckBox`es.

At this, I found that the `onClickListener` is aware of changes of the `CheckBox` not in the `MainAcitivity` but in the `CursorAdapter` class. So I coded that the id values are restored in a `ArrayList` whenever the `CheckBox`es are clicked, and returned when a method is called in `MainActivity`.

The problem is, I want for option menus to be changed if the `CheckBox` is checked (for example, `"DELETE"` and `"MOVE"` menu is unable when no `CheckBox` is checked, and enabled once `CheckBox`es are clicked), but don't know how.

#### Some parts of my `MainActivity` and `CursorAdapter`

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MenuItem itEdit, itSort, itView, itSelectAll, itDeselectAll, itDelete, itMove;
private boolean isEditChecked;

private ListView lvWords;
private WordAdapter wordadapter;
private ArrayList<Integer> checkedWords;
private Cursor wordCursor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvWords = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_words);

    dbhandler = DBHandler.open(this);
    wordCursor = dbhandler.selectWords(activeNoteId);

    wordadapter = new WordAdapter(this, wordCursor, isEditChecked);
    lvWords.setAdapter(wordadapter);

    ....
    ...
    ..
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    refreshListViews();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    itEdit = menu.findItem(R.id.it_edit);
    itSort = menu.findItem(R.id.it_sort);
    itView = menu.findItem(R.id.it_view);
    itSelectAll = menu.findItem(R.id.it_select_all);
    itDeselectAll = menu.findItem(R.id.it_deselect_all);
    itDelete = menu.findItem(R.id.it_delete);
    itMove = menu.findItem(R.id.it_move);

    itEdit.setVisible(true);
    itSort.setVisible(true);
    itView.setVisible(true);
    itSelectAll.setVisible(false);
    itDeselectAll.setVisible(false);
    itDelete.setVisible(false);
    itMove.setVisible(false);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ....
    ...
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.it_edit:
        onEditMenuClicked();
        break;
    case R.id.it_delete:
        checkedWords = wordadapter.getCheckedArrayList();
        final int checkedDeleteSize = checkedWords.size();
        ....
        ...     
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// when edit menu clicked
private void onEditMenuClicked() {
    isEditChecked = !isEditChecked;
    itSort.setVisible(!isEditChecked);
    itView.setVisible(!isEditChecked);
    itSelectAll.setVisible(isEditChecked);
    itDeselectAll.setVisible(isEditChecked);
    itDelete.setVisible(isEditChecked);
    itMove.setVisible(isEditChecked);

    wordadapter.setVisibility(isEditChecked);

    refreshListViews();
}

private void refreshListViews() {
    wordCursor.close();
    wordCursor = dbhandler.selectWords(activeNoteId);
    wordadapter.changeCursor(wordCursor);
    setVisibilityViews();
}
}
```

**WordAdapter.java**:

```
public class WordAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private boolean isCheckBoxVisable;
private ArrayList<Integer> checkedArray;
private boolean setCheck;

public WordAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean check) {
    super(context, c);
    isCheckBoxVisable = check;
    checkedArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    setCheck = false;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_list_word_check);

    final int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

    if(isCheckBoxVisable)
        check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else check.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {    
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            /////// I think something is added here /////

            if(isChecked){
                checkedArray.add(id);
            }
            else{
                checkedArray.remove(new Integer(id));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("newView()","start of newView");
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list_row, parent, false);
    Log.d("newView()","end of newView");
    return v;
}

// set visibility of checkbox
public void setVisibility(boolean check){
    isCheckBoxVisable = check;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getCheckedArrayList(){
    return checkedArray;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform a menu update, you must call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. It will call `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` back, were you can update (re-create) a menu depending on the state your activity is in.

Runtime changes in menu are explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu) in more details.